# Python script to delete files when the same files are copied to another directory

Tags: python, file-io

I'm brand new to Python and trying to write a script that deletes files in a particular directory when those same files have been copied to another directory (manually by someone or another automated event).

For organizational purposes.

Folder A = Files will be copied to Folder B and need to be deleted
Folder B = If Files copied match Files in Folder A then delete Files in Folder A
Constant Monitoring needed

I have no idea how to exactly start but I'm guessing the basic idea would be to have a watchdog monitoring Folder B for incoming files and match (filename is enough) with files from Folder A and then delete those files on Folder A.

So I just got a very very basic monitoring example to monitor incoming files in Folder B but from here I have no idea how to match them to Folder A to then take action on Folder A.

```
import sys, os
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

os.chdir(r"\\directory\FolderB")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Any pointers?

Many thanks in advance!

Only got as far as the previous code

Comment: None of your code is relevant to the question. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Might it be simpler to have a script to run on demand, rather than trying to do this when the files are moved or copied?